# Use of in a manner with adjectives

Tags: phrase-usage

*In a manner* confuses me in terms of use. Sometimes if i can’t find correct adverb i use adjective before manner . For example is it correct to say:

> My steel cylinder was delivered in a manner coated with aluminum.
>
> She was sent there in a compulsorily manner.

Answer (score 2):

"In a manner" is the way dictionaries explain many adverbs.  It isn't reversible.

"Compulsorily" is defined as "in a compulsory manner", but that doesn't mean you can actually say aloud, "She was sent there in a compulsory manner."  It's grammatically correct, but idiomatically wrong.

For example, "It's grammatically correct" sounds bizarre if you recast it as "It's correct in a grammatical manner."  You might say, "Its grammar is correct", but that's as close as you can get.

Your sentences should be

> My steel cylinder was delivered coated with aluminum.

"Coated with aluminum" functions as an adjective.

> She was compelled to go there.

(Or "They were compelled to send her there.")